# QML плагин с вложенными модулями QML. Как импортировать?

Tags: qt, qml

Собираю плагин QML.
Внутри плагина есть CPP и QML файлы.
QML файлов достаточно много, есть несколько вложенных папок со своими файлами.
Условно:
QML

- File01.qml
- File02.qml
- Folder1

  - File11.qml
  - File12.qml
  - qmldir ( внутри module Folder1 и ссылки на файлы)

В приложении, которое использует этот плагин ( import MyPlugin ) доступны только файлы самого верхнего уровня ( File01.qml, File02.qml).
Импорт вложенного модуля не работает  ( import MyPlugin.Folder1 ).  Еще существенное замечание - если в файле ресурсов добавить префикс /Folder1, то тогда будут доступны файлы из этого уровня (из Folder1 ), а из верхнего уровня пропадут.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нормально импортировать такую структуру и использовать такие плагины?